# Postman request redirecting regardless of option and/or setting when run in GitHub

Tags: django, postman, github-actions

I'm experiencing some odd behaviour when running my postman collection through the CLI using Newman specifically when running in my GitHub Actions CI/CD environment. For my collection two requests are done to set both the CSRF token and the sessionid that are necessary for the other requests. In order to do this through the CLI I programmatically set the cookies based on the request's response headers. However the second request is redirected a few times before reaching it's end point and to get the value I need for the sessionid I specifically need the first redirected request. Postman/Newman has an option for this called `--ignore-redirects` which fixes this problem when running locally and even through docker. However when running it on the GitHub's CI/CD it seems that this options is ignored as the behaviour it shows is the same as not using the option at all. This then causes my post-request test script to not be able to find the sessionid and set it in the collection variable. This in turn causes all other requests to fail because of a lack of a sessionid. Is there a way around this? Or should I consider a different tool for API testing? Seeing as postman currently has no method of programmatically sifting through redirecting requests.

Expected result:
`POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ [302 Found, 774B, 255ms]`

Actual result: `POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ [200 OK, 3.56kB, 261ms]`

Pre-request script:

```
// Because the response header "Set-Cookie" does not work when run in the CLI and CI/CD.
// Be sure to run the collection in CLI with the --ignore-redirects option, otherwise the sessionid cannot be fetched
console.log(pm.request.headers)
const cookies = pm.cookies.jar()
let csrfcookie = "";
let sesh = "";
// This part must only be run when the POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ is run
if (pm.request.method != 'GET' && pm.request.url == "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/") {
    csrfcookie = pm.collectionVariables.get("csrftoken")
    console.log(`reached1`)
    // Only POST methods need this header
    pm.request.headers.upsert({
        key: 'X-CSRFtoken',
        value: csrfcookie
    })
    cookies.set("backend", "csrftoken", csrfcookie)
}
// For all non "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/" requests this part is run
if(pm.request.url != "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/"){
    console.log(`reached2`)
    csrfcookie = pm.collectionVariables.get("csrftoken")
    sesh = pm.collectionVariables.get("sessionid")
    // Only POST methods need this header
    if(pm.request.method != 'GET'){
        pm.request.headers.upsert({
            key: 'X-CSRFtoken',
            value: csrfcookie
    })
    }
    // Cookies have to be set at the same time.
    cookies.set("backend", "csrftoken", csrfcookie, (error) => {
        cookies.set("backend", "sessionid", sesh);
    });
}
```

Post-request test:

```
// Only after request GET http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ should this run
// Because the POST method after requires it
if (pm.request.url == "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/" && pm.request.method == "GET"){
    let temp = pm.response.headers;
    let temp2 = temp.filter(item => item["key"]=== "Set-Cookie")
    let temp3 = temp2[0].value
    let temp4 = temp3.slice(10,42)
    pm.collectionVariables.set("csrftoken", temp4)
}
// Only after request POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/ should this run
// Because other methods after this require the CSRFtoken and sessionid
if (pm.request.url == "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/" && pm.request.method == "POST"){
    let temp5 = pm.response.headers;
    console.log(temp5)
    let temp6 = temp5.filter(item => item["key"]=== "Set-Cookie")
    let temp7 = temp6[0].value
    let temp8 = temp6[1].value
    let temp9 = temp7.slice(10,42)
    let temp10 = temp8.slice(10,42)
    pm.collectionVariables.set("csrftoken", temp9);
    pm.collectionVariables.set("sessionid", temp10);
}
```